# Implementing a uml class diagram on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml, implementation, diagram

I'm new on rails and I want to implement this diagram in Rails. The problem is with the heritage between classes, I don't know how to do that with models/controllers. Anyone have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Where is the diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails let your share features pretty easily among your models via 2 main pattern :

- [STI (single table inheritence)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Single+table+inheritance) : basically just add a type string column and inherit your model class from its parent instead of inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`
- [Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) : Share some features grouped into a module you defined and include it into your target model or controller's classes

On your controller side you can directly build your own inheritence chain (making sure the first ancestor is your ApplicationController), use the concern pattern or other types of goodies such as [Service Objects](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html) (and much much much more;-)  )

Comment: Thanks for the help !!